# Extending transaction scope timeout in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am running a PowerShell script to upgrade my database. I have implemented transactionscope to rollback changes in case of script errors. Upgrade scripts take a long time to complete on certain databases. In such long running cases transaction scope gives up after 10 minutes though I have set a long timeout period. Below is the code snippet I have implemented.

```
    $timeout = New-Object System.TimeSpan -ArgumentList @(24,0,0) # 24 hours
$options = [System.Transactions.TransactionScopeOption]::Required
$scope = New-Object -TypeName System.Transactions.TransactionScope -ArgumentList @($options,$timeout)
Try{
    Write-Output "SQL Transaction initiated"
    $SqlFiles | Foreach-Object {
        $sqlFile = $_
        Write-Output "$((get-date).ToString('T')) - Processing file: $sqlFile"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ErrorAction 'Stop' -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Username $Username -Password $Password -InputFile $sqlFile -Variable $SQLParameters
        Write-Output "$((get-date).ToString('T')) - Completed file:  $sqlFile"
    }
     $scope.Complete() 
}
catch{
    Write-Output "$((get-date).ToString('T')) - SQL error occured rolling back transaction"
    throw $_.exception
}
finally{
    $scope.Dispose() 
}
```

May I know what can I do to increase the transaction scope timeout? I tried updating transaction scope in the machine.config but it did not help.

Thank you.